# Is there a way to capture the order of a slicer selection using DAX?

Tags: dax

Is there a way to capture the sequence a person selects a slicer using DAX?

For example:

- 12th
- 3rd
- 2nd
- 22nd

Currently, I am using this DAX code to capture the values selected. However, the returning values are in alphabetical order each time rather than in order of selection.

```
SelectedProjectTitleValues = CONCATENATEX( VALUES('PROJECT'[PROJECT_TITLE]), 'PROJECT'[PROJECT_TITLE], UNICHAR(10))
```

Any support would be appreciated. Thank you for taking to time to help me with this.

Kind regards

Comment: I don't think it's possible, DAX is not designed for this type of tasks. I'd also say, it feels like a very weird requirement. Try to state your objective in more general, conceptual terms - maybe there is a better way.

Comment: I need to be able to track the order of the selection as I have two slicers (A/B).  I then want to create a dynamic table (by ROW) that reflects the sequence of the selection.

e.g. 
Slicer A = 4,77,2
Slicer B = 5,9

Result:

SlicerA Row 1 = 4
SlicerA Row 2 = 77
SlicerA Row 3 = 2

SlicerB Row 1 = 5
SlcierB Row 2 = 9

Comment: It sounds to me like a classic case of https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: OK.  I will try to explain my objective in a more general way ;-)

To allow a user to select a "pair" of values (from a list) and to be able to compare them against each other.  However, this needs to work for multiple selections and not just a single pair.

Comment: As RADO says, this is not possible unfortunately. PowerBI just sees the column of values.

Answer (score 0):

Power Pivot as a feature to sort a column (usually textual) by another column (usually numeric). See https://superuser.com/questions/1295640/in-power-bi-how-do-i-sort-slicer-values-other-than-by-name . So you can use this to sort values presented by the slicer, and also to sort values returned by the slicer.

Comment: OP asked for the sequence in which a user selects the options which is not possible.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I misunderstood the question